# How to ensure the API response for a request is JSON type in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to login to the tableau rest API in apps script and then get all the available views under a workbook. I'm authenticating via PATs and on successful sign-in I receive a response from the API that looks like XML response.
Here's the fetch code for that:

```
function tableauTM() {
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(
      {
        credentials: {
          personalAccessTokenName: 'Tableau', 
          personalAccessTokenSecret: '<token_secret>',  
          site: {
            contentUrl: 'pixybi', 
          },
        },
      }
    ),
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'https://10ay.online.tableau.com/api/3.13/auth/signin', options
    
    );
     
  Logger.log(response)
```

This is the response text I receive:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api https://help.tableau.com/samples/en-us/rest_api/ts-api_3_13.xsd"><credentials token="1j4LgLC1TQagsevrKPwJEw|VGo4bJwHbRQPRYxuOaeHhnsVth7nNc3e" estimatedTimeToExpiration="363:04:39"><site id="c3f66f3d-1112-4bff-a5f4-b4022e303d13" contentUrl="udacitybi"/><user id="c34bf5f6-86b8-4de6-a619-f68837bce120"/></credentials></tsResponse>
```

How to ensure that the response is of JSON type and if that's not possible how can
one extract the attribute values for fields like token, user, and site id?

We tried the below code but it's throwing the type error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChild' of null`

```
  var root = XmlService.parse(response).getRootElement().getChild('credentials').getChild('user').getAttribute('id').getValue()
```

Comment: `Accept` should be a Header. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/info) for reference page.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse XML using [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service). Based on your error message, no root element exists, therefore you should first try [hasRootElement()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/document#hasrootelement) before calling [getRootElement()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/document#getrootelement). Instead you can try [getDescendants()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/document#getdescendants) and log out its result.

Fix your `options` by adding Headers under the `headers` parameter. See the [UrlFetch Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl,-params). Basically, see `headers` below for what I mean. Hopefully this should enable you to receive `JSON`.

```
const options = {
    method: 'post',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }, …
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the Accept in headers worked out well. @neven-subotic

Comment: Please mark as resolved :)